# How to calculate the total number of Datastore reads/writes in an App Engine SDK local test environment?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine application, and would like to compare the estimated costs of its current design against a new design.  Basically I would like to:

1. run both versions of my codebase in a local App Engine Java SDK test environment,
2. capture some key statistics from each one (primarily the number of Datastore reads and writes), and then
3. compile and compare the two sets of statistics.

I am aware of the "Appstats" tool, and it would be great to make some use of it if possible.  However, it has two serious shortcomings:

1. Appstats stores only the most recent 1,000 records, which is too small for the scale of the test operations I need to run.
2. Appstats provides a "estimated cost" for App Engine, rather than a precise number of Datastore reads and writes.  To make a long story short, knowing the total exact number of reads and writes would be useful to me.

When I run an application locally in the Java SDK test environment, I can pull up the Admin Console's Datastore Viewer, and see the exact number of write ops that have occurred for each individual entity in the datastore.  Awesome!

Unfortunately though, I am dealing with tens or hundreds of thousands of entities, and the Datastore Viewer only displays 10 per browser page.  :(  So, short of having to write a hacky screen-scraping solution... I need some programmatic access to the information that Datastore Viewer uses to display those numbers.  Assuming that such programmatic access is available at all, it would be great it also offered other Datastore-related stats (e.g. reads).

Is any such programmatic access to the local SDK environment metadata available?  Alternatively, does anyone have a completely different approach for capturing such stats from a local test run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Datastore

This is actually pretty simple to calculate on an Entity by Entity basis.

Store one average fully populated record, look a the console and see how many writes it took, that is about all you can do to see what the writes are.

The only way to reduce writes is to mark attributes as "unindexed". I reduced a couple of Entities from 8 writes to 2 by doing this.

Reads are easy too, only read what you need and put stuff you need multiple times in `memcache` and only persist it when you really need to.

#### Images

Serve images from the `ImageService` those are free.

#### Binaries/Blobs

Serve binaries from the Cloud Store, you only pay for storage, no read/write fees or bandwidth fees.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to avoid estimating the writes based on a "(num_of_entities * writes_per_entity_type)" formula, because there is a lot of variance in how densely or sparsely our entities are populated... and thus I don't have confidence in the second variable of that formula.  However, it probably is the most convenient approach.